# Properties of groups of order $p^3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For non-abelian groups $G$ such that $|G|=p^3$ one can show that

$(1)$ $Z=Z(G)\cong C_p$

$(2)$ $G'=Z$

Now want to show that $G/Z \cong C_p \times C_p$. So,

If $G/Z \cong C_{p^2}$, take its generator, say $\overline{g}$. Then $G=\langle z, \overline{g}\rangle$ which would mean that $G$ is abelian.

Now for $g \in Z$, we have $C(g)= \{g\}$. This would be the same in any group.

> Apparently for $g \not\in Z$ we have that $C(g)=\{e,g,gz,gz^2,\dots,gz^{p-1} \}$

I cannot see why the highlighted region holds.

Comment: Sorry how does that help explain the highlighted region?

Comment: Your first sentence applies to *nonabelian* groups of order $p^3$.

Comment: Also your notation is confusing. $C(g)$ usually denotes the centralizer of $g$, not the conjugacy class of $g$.

Comment: 1) You are correct. 2) I have changed this to make it a little clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an element $g\in G$ which is not in the center $Z$.

The centralizer of $g$ is the set of $h\in G$ such that $hg=gh$. Obviously this is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $Z$.

By Lagrange, its cardinal is either $1,p,p^2,p^3$.

Because $g\notin Z$ the cardinal of its centralizer cannot be $p^3$. Furthermore it contains $Z$ and $g$ hence its cardinal is $>p$ hence the cardinal of the centralizer of any non-central element is $p^2$.

Finally I claim that $C(g)$ the centralizer of $g$ will be $C(g)=<g,Z>$ which is what is highlighted.

However $C(g)=G$ for $g\in G$ and this is the conjugacy class of $g\in Z$ which is equal to $\{g\}$.

Comment: I think we might have had a mix up in notation. $C(g)$ is this case means conjugacy class of $g$. I also cannot understand your last two sentences.

Comment: @sandstone, yes however in the highlighted sentence you said that $C(g)$ contains $e$. Actually what you have written in the sentence is exactly the centralizer. That is why Derek Holt said that you mixed up notations... I think you can always express the centralizer but not the conjugacy class.

Comment: @sandstone there was a mistake in my two last sentences. Now it should make more sense. In the last sentence I just say that the centralizer of a central element is the whole group (by definition) whereas the conjugacy class of a central element is a one-element set which just contains the element.

Comment: @sandstone. Now to compute the centralizer of $g\notin Z$, by what I have written it is a subgroup which necessarily contains $<Z,g>$. This last group is a group whose order is $p^2$ or $p^3$ and contained in the centralizer. Hence its order is $p^2$ and it is exactly the centralizer of $g$.